# Extracting character strings from images of such strings?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

I have an idea of sorting through IC chips based on their types for a design project. Of course, the information about each device is printed on the top in a string of characters:

[image]

The idea is that we could take a picture of this device, and process the image and extract the string `"74AC139PC."` The basis of the project would be taking a bin of random DIP chips and sorting through them to find the ones associated with a string input to the program by a user.

How difficult would it be to extract such information from an image? The process is simplified because most chips have a nice white/gold text overlaid onto a black background. Further, the text is usually formatted just like the image above, so no fancy text is used.

Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: I hear people use opencv

Comment: How can this question be made any more specific? I came to ask because I do not know where to begin. I did not come to ask how it can be done with a specific library or software tool. I have no idea where to begin insofar as the image processing is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few OCR libraries or more general computer vision libraries you can use, some of which are open source. Tesseract (https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is the first that comes to my mind, but there are others.